# Why do I get "Server not found in Kerberos database" using testsaslauthd?

Tags: linux, windows, openldap, kerberos, sasl

I'm trying to setup Kerberos auth over SASL using OpenLDAP. As I understand it, I need a host keytab in `/etc/krb5.keytab` from the KDC I'm using and then `{SASL}user@realm` in the given user's LDAP password attribute. Switching users from *root* > *nobody* > *user101* (with password) appears to work with a Linux KDC. Testing SASL via `testsaslauthd` is also succesful for *user101* using the Linux KDC.

As soon as I switch keytab and server over to the production KDC however (2012 Server AD.MYCORP.COM below), I get *Server not found in Kerberos database* in the auth log. Some searching turns up possible rDNS issues as the culprit. I've added `rdns = false` in my `krb5.conf` and a few other settings trying to pin this down with no luck. I can get a forward DNS reply for AD.MYCORP.COM but the reverse **does** come back with a different hostname.

The windows admin sent me this error log with the closest timestamp matching the error in the Linux auth log. It seems to suggest an encryption algorithm issue, and not DNS. He is in the process of resetting the password on the service account but haven't heard back from him yet:
*While processing a TGS request for the target server
host/auth-test-ldap.mynet.net, the account user101@AD.MYCORP.COM did not have
a suitable key for generating a Kerberos ticket (the missing key has an ID of 8).
The requested etypes were 18. The accounts available etypes were 23  -133  -128  18  17.
Changing or resetting the password of SVC-KEYTAB-MYNET2 will generate a proper key.*

Is DNS most likely the problem? Any further way to debug on the Linux end? Config and logs using the Windows KDC and keytab are below.

**/etc/krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
   default_realm = AD.MYCORP.COM
   krb4_config   = /etc/krb.conf
   krb4_realms   = /etc/krb.realms
   kdc_timesync  = 1
   ccache_type   = 4
   forwardable   = true
   proxiable     = true

   default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
   default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
   permitted_enctypes   = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 des3-cbc-sha1 arcfour-hmac-md5 camellia256-cts-cmac camellia128-cts-cmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-md

   rdns             = false
   dns_lookup_realm = false
   dns_lookup_kdc   = false

[login]
   krb4_convert     = true
   krb4_get_tickets = false

[realms]
   AD.MYCORP.COM = {
                   kdc          = ad.mycorp.com
                   admin_server = ad.mycorp.com
                 }

[domain_realm]
   .ad.mycorp.com = AD.MYCORP.COM
   ad.mycorp.com  = AD.MYCORP.COM
```

**kinit with keytab and host principal works**

```
# kinit -k host/auth-test-ldap.mynet.net@AD.MYCORP.COM
```

**klist the cache, looks ok**

```
# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: host/auth-test-ldap.mynet.net@AD.MYCORP.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/02/2020 09:10:48  11/02/2020 19:10:48  krbtgt/AD.MYCORP.COM@AD.MYCORP.COM
        renew until 11/03/2020 09:10:48
```

**test user auth**

```
# read -s PASS; testsaslauthd -u user101 -p $PASS -s ldap
```

**/var/log/auth.log**

```
Nov  2 09:11:07 auth-test-ldap saslauthd[714]: auth_krb5: krb5_mk_req(): Server not found in Kerberos database (-1765328377)
Nov  2 09:11:07 auth-test-ldap saslauthd[714]: auth_krb5: k5support_verify_tgt
Nov  2 09:11:07 auth-test-ldap saslauthd[714]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=user101] [service=ldap] [realm=] [mech=kerberos5] [reason=saslauthd internal error]
```

Comment: Have you checked what server name saslauthd is actually trying to obtain tickets for? (Sure, it's _supposed_ to be the server that saslauthd is running on, but is that actually what happens? Have you looked at the TGS_REQs in tcpdump to see what they contain?) And on the topic of algorithms, I wonder why your krb5.conf still lists DES as permitted? Why does it still contain Kerberos 4 options? Kerberos 4 should not exist in 2020...

Comment: I added a bunch of other algorithms after reading *the requested etypes were 18* message may be due to permitted encryption types being too restrictive so DES made it in there just in case. The krb4 stuff was from an example which is apparently very old. How do I decrypt the kerberos session to view the TGS request (via tcpdump)?

Answer (score 2):

I did an update and then did a realm leave and then a join. That took care of the problem for me. I followed all that I could find on the internet including the above and it seemed like nothing worked until I did this.

Good luck.